# How to handle dataframes as instance variables in python

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop

All,

I don't see similar questions online, if there are please kindly guide me to that question.

Here is what I am trying to do:

- I have a class that builds a financial model in a data frame (so there are several tens of columns in the data frame)
- Each column has a formula and many of the columns use the information in the prior columns

Can someone please recommend what is a good way to approach this problem.

```py
# import required libraries 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

class DataFrameInClass: 
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int): 
        self.a = a 
        self.b = b 
        self.df = pd.DataFrame() 

    def get_df(self) -> pd.DataFrame: 
        return pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(self.a,self.b,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

    def set_df(self): 
        self.df = self.get_df 

    def calculate_A_square(self) -> pd.Series: 
        # Approach 1 - calculate each column individually 
        df = self.df.copy(deep=True)
        df['A_Square'] = df['A'] ** 2
        return pd.Series(data=df['A_Square'], index=df.index) 

    def calculate_A_cubed(self): 
        # Approach 2 - Modify data frame 
        self.df['A_Cubed'] = self.df['A'] ** 3
```

I am not sure if it is good practice to just modify the dataframe within each method (Can someone please help me understand that a little better). Or should I recalculate the columns in each method (that also feels like a bad idea).
For e.g. In the below case, if a_square value was made an instance variable, I could calculate a_cubed in one line. However that would also mean my class would have just so many instance variables

Comment: I would go clubbing the data frame operations in one function and then return the updated data frame. for example, in the constructor, you can build the `self.df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(self.a,self.b,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))` and then call `calculate_A_square` and  then `
        self.df['A_Square'] = self.df['A'] ** 2       
and then
        self.df['A_Cubed'] = self.df['A'] ** 3 `

Comment: @simpleApp, 
     I have over 150 columns where several column calculations would require multiple steps. If they were clubbed into one function, wouldn't that then make the function so complicated ? Additionally, shouldn't a function typically do one thing alone.

Comment: agree, I did not mean to dump in all operations in one function if they are not cohesive.  there is definitely a trade-off. If you are building a pipeline then it's better to keep operations in one place.